# Writing a loop to output pathnames with multiple variables

Tags: r, loops, data-manipulation

I have a `dataframe` named "List" as follows:

| Name | Institution | Department |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Adam | A | xxx |
| Eve | B | yyy |
| John | A | zzz |
| Jane | C | xxx |

I have another `dataframe` of other data where I want to extract info from using the names - no problem with this part.

My problem comes in when trying to get the file_path with multiple variable inputs.

How do I have a loop to read the variables in each line to get the file_path properly:

```
parent_dir<-"Documents/Files"
        
for (i in List$Name) {
name <- i
        
for (j in List$Institution) {
inst <- j
        
for (k in List$Department) {
dept<-k

file_path<-paste0(parent_dir,"/",inst,"/",dept,"/",name,".xlsx")

answer <- data[is.element(Data$Name, i), ]
file.copy(template_path,file_path)
wb<-loadWorkbook(file_path,create = FALSE)
writeWorksheet(wb,answer,sheet="Staff",header=FALSE)
saveWorkbook(wb,file_path)

}}}
```

What I would like to do is end up with the following `file_path` for each row from the `dataframe`:

```r
 "/Documents/Files/A/xxx/Adam.xlsx"
 "/Documents/Files/B/yyy/Eve.xlsx"
 "/Documents/Files/A/zzz/John.xlsx"
 "/Documents/Files/C/xxx/Jane.xlsx"
```

What I get now is:

> "Adam.xlxs" in "A/xxx" and "A/zzz"

or other error messages like:

> directory "A/yyy" does not exist.

This chunk works fine if it's just 1 loop/variable:

```
for (i in List$Name) {
        
    file_path<-paste0(parent_dir,"/",i,".xlsx")

    answer <- data[is.element(Data$Name, i), ]
    file.copy(template_path,file_path)
    wb<-loadWorkbook(file_path,create = FALSE)
    writeWorksheet(wb,answer,sheet="Staff",header=FALSE)
    saveWorkbook(wb,file_path)
    }
```

Any other suggestion/solution is also welcome!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use an `apply` loop and instead of `paste`, use `file.path` to form the filename without extension. Then `paste0` the extension.

```
parent_dir<-"Documents/Files"
apply(List, 1, \(x, parent_dir, ext){
  f <- file.path(parent_dir, x[2], x[3], x[1])
  paste0(f, ext)
}, parent_dir = parent_dir, ext = ".xlsx")
#[1] "Documents/Files/A/xxx/Adam.xlsx"
#[2] "Documents/Files/B/yyy/Eve.xlsx" 
#[3] "Documents/Files/A/zzz/John.xlsx"
#[4] "Documents/Files/C/xxx/Jane.xlsx"
```

Note: to have a bar `"/"` before the path name add it to `parent_dir`:

```
parent_dir <- "/Documents/Files"
```

---

### Data

```
List <- read.table(text = "
Name    Institution     Department
Adam    A   xxx
Eve     B   yyy
John    A   zzz
Jane    C   xxx
", header = TRUE)
```